# Strange Behaviour with Scanf() in xcode

Tags: c, xcode

```
int P;
printf("Print a Character:");
scanf("%d",&P);
printf("\n The character you pressed was %d",P);
```

Without me inputting any number, this outputs:

"Print a Character:

The character you pressed was -1073750520"

Do you know why this would be?  I'm using Xcode.

Comment: You might also try fgets(stdin,buffer,sizeof(buffer)); and then printf("%s",buffer); to see what is on stdin. I don't know much about xcode but maybe you have some weird config or something being piped in on stdin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is something already present in the `stdin` stream. So flushing the stream could help.

Try `fflush(stdin);` before `scanf();`.

But `fflush(stdin)` is undefined behavior.

Comment: I apologize for wasting your time. I actually started my project as a single view, rather than a command line program.  I will give you best answer though.

Comment: +1 because you mentioned it is undefined behaviour :)